# jQuery - n.blur is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code isn't working. The console says `n.blur is not a function`.

```
var name = '',
    formElement = '',
    fullname = $('.form input[name="user"]'),
    email = $('.form input[name="pass"]');

$('.form input').click(function() {
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    formElement = $('.form input[name="'+name+'"]');
});

formElement.blur(function() {
    if(formElement.val().length === 0) {
        formElement.closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    } else {
        formElement.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

Comment: You aren't defining `formElement` until the `click` event, how do you expect it to work?

Answer (score 2):

There's no `blur` method since at that point `formElement` is a string:

```
var name = '',
    formElement = '',
    ...
```

Comment: @HarardDype We can't tell you what to do. Your code doesn't make any sense and you haven't told us anything beyond "This code isn't working". Please tell us how you _want_ it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need your `.click()` function and can attach your `blur()` to all the .form inputs:

```
$('.form input').blur(function() {
    formElement = $(this);
    if(formElement.val().length === 0) {
        formElement.closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    } else {
        formElement.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

That should achieve the same effect.